# Custom order based on Enum values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this defined Enum for roles:

```
enum role: {ordinary: 0, manager: 1, admin: 2}
```

I would liked to order a collection of objects in the following order:

```
admin (first all admins)
ordinary (then all ordinaries)
manager (and lastly all managers)
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A solution for this:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLE_ORDERS = [2, 0, 1]

  scope :order_by_role, -> {
    order_by = ['CASE']
    ROLE_ORDERS.each_with_index do |role, index|
      order_by << "WHEN role=#{role} THEN #{index}"
    end
    order_by << 'END'
    order(order_by.join(' '))
  }
end
```

Then your query will be simple like this:

```
YourModel.order_by_role
```

The generated query is:

```
SELECT * from your_models
ORDER BY ( CASE
           WHEN role=2 THEN 0
           WHEN role=0 THEN 1
           WHEN role=1 then 2
           END
         )
```

Good reference from [this](https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737)

Comment: This is pretty brilliant.  Looks ugly, but great solution IMO to an otherwise very sticky issue.

Answer (score 7):

Starting Rails 6.0, [@hieu-pham's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599787/1091231) will throw this deprecation warning: "Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s) [..] Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.1. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql()."

So, building up on both his answer and [@fellow-stranger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37600380/1091231), I'd suggest this:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLE_ORDERS = [2, 0, 1]
  scope :order_by_role, -> { order(Arel.sql(ROLE_ORDERS.map{ |role| "role=#{role} DESC" }.join(', '))) }
end
```

Then this is used in your code just as in [@hieu-pham's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599787/1091231)...

```
YourModel.order_by_role
```

... which generates this query:

```
SELECT * from your_models
ORDER BY role = 2 DESC, role = 0 DESC, role = 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 7):

### ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#in_order_of (Rails 7+)

---

Starting from **Rails 7**, there is a new method [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#in_order_of](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of).

A quote right from the official Rails docs:

> in_order_of(column, values)

> Allows to specify an order by a specific set of values. Depending on your adapter this will either use a CASE statement or a built-in function.

```
User.in_order_of(:id, [1, 5, 3])
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY FIELD("users"."id", 1, 5, 3)
```

---

It works with model enums as well:

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:proposed, :written, :published]
end

Book.in_order_of(:status, %w[written published proposed])
```

---

**Sources:**

- Official docs - [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#in_order_of](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of).
- PR - [Add ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#in_order_of](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42061).
- [More examples](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/395ea07419e12c78c8e03d37bd412606c33d9045/activerecord/test/cases/relation/field_ordered_values_test.rb).

Comment: This is great news! I always hoped Rails would incorporate a query method like this 

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073332/1417223) I came up with this:

```
order("role = 0 DESC, role = 1 DESC, role = 2 DESC")
```

Or, as a scope with optional arguments:

```
scope :order_by_roles, -> (first = :admin, second = :ordinary, third = :manager) { 
  order("role = #{User.roles[first]} DESC, role = #{User.roles[second]} DESC, role = #{User.roles[third]} DESC") 
}
```