# How to sort enum with Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I've got a table `users` with enum role set like this:

```
enum role: {
    superadmin: 0,
    admin: 1,
    user: 2
}
```

And I want to sort it with Ransack like the rest of the attributes. How can I do this?

Of course, I could sort them alphabetically, but what if I want to add another role in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I made a function based off the answer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599787/2055858

```
def alphabetical_enum_sql(enum, field_name)
    ordered_enum = enum.keys.sort
    order_by = ["case"]
    ordered_enum.each_with_index do |key, idx|
        order_by << "WHEN #{field_name}=#{enum[key]} THEN #{idx}"
    end
    order_by << "end"
    order_by.join(" ")
end
```

and then used it like

```
scope :order_by_role, -> {
   order(alphabetical_enum_sql(YourModel.roles, "role"))
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it will not work with Ransack.